# Print Fit to Paper C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, printing

**About**
I'm using WinForms. In my Form I have a open and print button. The Open button opens tif images into a picturebox. The print button prints these pictures from the picture box. I work with big image documents, for example width and length: (3000, 3600). So i scaled these tif image documents to fit to the regular printing paper size (8.5 x 11). The reason i did this is so the letters on the tif image wont be blurry using the method below.

**Issue**
The good news is it scaled nicely meaning its not blurry. The bad news is it scaled down to much. See Figure A.2

**Test**

Test i increased and decreased the * 100 the weird thing is it does not increase the size but it decreases the size

> ```
> float newWidth = i.Width * 100 / i.HorizontalResolution;
> float newHeight = i.Height * 100 / i.VerticalResolution;
> ```

**Code**

```
        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        { //pageViewer = picturebox
            Image i = pageViewer.Image;

            float newWidth = i.Width * 100 / i.HorizontalResolution;
            float newHeight = i.Height * 100 / i.VerticalResolution;

            float widthFactor = newWidth / e.MarginBounds.Width;
            float heightFactor = newHeight / e.MarginBounds.Height;

            if (widthFactor > 1 | heightFactor > 1)
            {
                if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
                {
                    newWidth = newWidth / widthFactor;
                    newHeight = newHeight / widthFactor;
                }
                else
                {
                    newWidth = newWidth / heightFactor;
                    newHeight = newHeight / heightFactor;
                }
            }
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, 0, 0, (int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);
        }
```

**How its suppose to print**

[image]

**How it is currently printing**
Figure A.2
[image]

Comment: Code seems to work, except you are printing in the margins.  Try `e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, (int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);`

Comment: I tested this right now. What it did was centered the image, but the image is still scaled down to small. @LarsTech

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual image you are using from pageViewer.Image?

Comment: I can provide a link, let me make that

Comment: Good example image;
`http://www.filedropper.com/goodprint`   


What it is currently doing:
`http://www.filedropper.com/stackcenteredimage`

Comment: That image has a thick white border around the text.  Use e.PageBounds instead of e.MarginBounds and go back to printing at the 0, 0 location again.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I don't know why i got voted down though :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image already contains a margin, so when you use the e.MarginBounds property, you are effectively doubling your margins.  To fix, use the PageBounds property instead.

```
float widthFactor = newWidth / e.PageBounds.Width;
float heightFactor = newHeight / e.PageBounds.Height;
```

Comment: Thank you once again LarsTech you have been really helpful :)